# Drag and drop items from listbox to desktop

Tags: vb.net

I have a ListBox control, that contains a few items that display attachments (files or directories).

I have successfully allowed users to drag and drop items from their desktop to the ListBox , but I have not been able to allow the user to drag and drop items from the ListBox to their desktop.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps you get started (assuming list box is just a list of files with their full paths):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
  Dim fileList As New Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
  fileList.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

  Dim dataObj As New DataObject
  dataObj.SetFileDropList(fileList)

  ListBox1.DoDragDrop(dataObj, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to prevent dragging back onto self - [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11754362/737393)